# Solving $\int_{0}^{x}(x-t)y(t)dt = 2x+\int_{0}^{x}y(t)dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve:

$$
\int_{0}^{x}(x-t)y(t)dt = 2x + \int_{0}^{x}y(t)dt
$$

---

The farthest I got is to:

$$
\int_{0}^{x}(x-t)y(t)dt-\int_{0}^{x}y(t)dt = 2x
$$

Combining the integrals we get:

$$
\int_{0}^{x}y(t)(x-t-1)dt = 2x
$$

And here I’m pretty stuck.

Can someone please give me a hint?

Thanks.

Comment: Solve in what variable(s)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\int_{0}^{x}(x-t)y(t)dt = 2x+\int_{0}^{x}y(t)dt~~~(1)$$
$$\implies x \int_{0}^{x} y(t) dt-\int_{0}^{x} t y(t) dt=2x+\int_{0}^{x} y(t) dt$$
D.w.t.t. $x$ using Lebnitz
$$\int_{0}^{x}  y(t) dt+ x y(x)-xy(x)=2+y(x)$$
$$\implies \int_{0}^{x} y(t) dt=2+y(x) \implies y(0)=-2~~~~(2)$$
Again D.w.r.t. $x$
$$y(x)=y'(x) \implies y=C e^{x} \implies y(x)=-2e^{x}$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint :** Differentiate
$$\int_{0}^{x}(x-t)y(t)dt = 2x + \int_{0}^{x}y(t)dt$$

w.r.t. $x$. You get
$$ \int_0^x y(t) dt = 2 + y(x)$$

Defining $Y : x \mapsto \int_0^x y(t) dt$, this can be rewritten as
$$Y'(x) -Y(x) + 2 = 0$$

You can conclude by yourself !

Answer (score 1):

Hint: This is quite easy if you split LHS as $x\int_o^{x}y(t)dt-\int_0^{x}ty(t)dt$ and differentiate the equation twice w.r.t. $x$.

Assuming only existence of the integrals involved you can say that $y(x)=-2e^{x}$ almost everywhere.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why we know that we can differentiate? For example, shouldn't it be $y$ at least continuous?

Comment: Indefinite integral of  an integrable function is continuous and differentiable almost everywhere. This  justifies first  differentiation. After that you see immediately that $y$ is almost evreywhere equal to a continuous function. Replacing $y$ by this function you also see from the equation you now have that $y$ is differentiable too. @ZaWarudo

Answer (score 0):

Let $y(x)$ be a solution of the integral equation:

$$\tag{IE} \int_{0}^{x}(x-t)\ y(t)\ \text{d}t = 2x + \int_{0}^{x} y(t)\ \text{d} t\; ;$$

hence, by definition of solution, $y \in C^0(I)$ (where $I\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is a suitable neighbourhood of $0$) and both sides of (**IE**) are differentiable w.r.t. $x \in I$.
Therefore we can differentiate the equation to get:

$$\int_{0}^{x} y(t)\ \text{d}t = 2 + y(x) $$

or:

$$\tag{A} y(x) = \int_0^x y(t)\ \text{d} t - 2\; ;$$

from (**A**) we infer that $y(x)$ is differentiable w.r.t. $x\in I$, thus we can differentiate another time to get:

$$y^\prime (x) = y(x)\; ,$$

which is a first order ODE. If we plug $x=0$ in (**A**) we obtain:

$$y(0) = -2\; ,$$

therefore a solution of your (**IE**) also solves (locally) the first order linear Cauchy problem:

$$\tag{CP} \begin{cases} y^\prime (x) = y(x) \\ y(0) = -2 \end{cases}\; .$$

On the other hand, if we retrace the steps, we can prove that the maximal (or any local) solution of (**CP**) also solves (**IE**); therefore (**IE**) and (**CP**) are equivalent and we can solve (**CP**)  in order to get the solution of (**IE**).

Thus the unique solution of (**IE**) is obviously:

$$y(x) = -2\ e^x\; .$$

---

Let me remark that you can also assume lesser regularity on the solution $y(x)$ without changing the argument. In fact, even if you assume the weaker notion of solution, i.e. $y \in L^1(I)$, previous reasoning applies to reduce (**IE**) to (**CP**).